# apache 2.2 and http auth. by country with mod_geoip

Tags: apache-2.2, geoip, setenv

I'm using mod_geoip for filtr some traffic. So now I have e.g. this

```
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE FR AllowCountry
<Locationmatch "/secure-by-country">
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
</..
```

But now I need add http auth. for blocked countries. So:

if IP **is not** from env=AllowCountry show http auth and if client send valid credentian allow access.

It is possible? How I can mix Locationmatch & Mod_geoip with some type of IF?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have it:) - Allow and require must be in valid order

```
<Locationmatch "/secure-by-country">
AuthName "Secure area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/.../.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowCountry
require valid-user
</Locationmatch>
```